# Preventing default behavior for tab stops listeners from working

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to dynamically create an input field and implement a tab autocomplete feature. Unfortunately, whenever I listen for a tab and call preventDefault on the keydown event to stop the tab from focusing on other fields, the keypress listener cannot register a tab.

```
var element = document.createElement("input");


//Assign different attributes to the element.
element.setAttribute("type", "text");
element.setAttribute("value", "");
element.setAttribute("name", "Test Name");
element.setAttribute("spellcheck", "false");
element.setAttribute("style", "width:400px");
element.classList.add('text');


element.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 9){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

element.onkeypress = function(e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 13){
        // code
    } else if(keyCode == 9) {
        console.log("detected"); //never printed to console
    } 

}
```

How can I stop the tab from doing default behavior while also adding my own functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keypress gets fired after keydown, and since you prevent the default behaviour in keydown, I think that it prevents the keypress event from being fired. You should try putting it in the same event handler, or handlers on the same event, but that might be tricky, since nothing guarantees the order in which it gets executed.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.